# Why is the title "Friseuse" considered as inappropriate?

Tags: word-usage, politeness

I learned that I should not entitle a female hairdresser *"Friseuse"* as this may be considered as rude.

Duden lists [*"Friseuse"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Friseuse) as both, colloquial and antiquated, and recommends the usage of the appropriate title *"Friseurin"*

Why is it that *"Friseuse"* is now considered as inappropriate? Are there any references for that?

[Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Friseuse,Friseurin&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) indicate, that this is a relatively young process where the usage of *Friseurin* surpasses *Friseuse* only after 2000:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117693/discussion-on-question-by-takkat-why-is-the-title-friseuse-considered-as-inapp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Sprachwissenschaftlerin Antje Oldenburg (1998) sieht zwei Gründe für die Verdrängung des Lehnsuffixes *-euse* durch das deutsche Suffix *-in*.

Da die ursprünglich neutrale Berufsbezeichnung *Masseuse* im Laufe der Zeit die Zusatzbedeutung "Prostituierte" annahm, wurde es notwendig die Berufsbezeichung von dieser Bedeutung abzugrenzen. Dafür wurde das Suffix *-euse* durch das Suffix *-in* ersetzt. Diese Bedeutungsdifferenzierung breitete sich daraufhin auf andere Berufsbezeichnungen aus, mit der Folge, dass Berufsbezeichnungen mit *-euse* erotisiert und abgewertet erscheinen.

Feministische Wissenschaftlerinnen sehen eine Verteilung der Berufsbezeichnungen nach Berufsgruppen, wobei Berufe mit der weiblichen Endung *-in* eher prestigeträchtigeren Berufsgruppen (Ingenieurin, Regisseurin), Berufe mit *-euse* eher dem Niedriglohnsektor (Friseuse, Masseuse) zuzurechnen sind. (Pober, 2007) Die Verwendung der Endung *-in* kommt somit nicht nur einer Entsexualisierung sondern auch einem Versuch der Aufwertung der Berufsgruppe selbst gleich, wie sie sich auch bei der Neubezeichnung der Bauern als Landwirte findet.

Der zweite Grund ist das Aufkommen geschlechtsneutral formulierter Stellenanzeigen, in denen sich das Suffix *-in* besser an die männliche Berufsbezeichnung anfügen lässt als das Suffix *-euse*: Ingenieur/-in oder Ingenieur(in). Dasselbe ist mit der Endung *-euse* nicht möglich: Friseur/-euse ergäbe Friseureuse und Friseu(r/se) ist schlicht Unfug.

*Literatur*

- Oldenburg, Antje (1998). Von Arzthelfern, Bauschlosserinnen und anderen Berufstätigen: Zum Gebrauch von Personenbezeichnungen in Stellenanzeigen. Muttersprache, 108(1), 67–80.
- Pober, Maria (2007). Gendersymmetrie. Würzburg: Königshausen & Neumann.

Comment: Gibt es denn mehr Bezeichnungen mit ~euse? Zwei Fälle, um darauf eine Regel aufzubauen, erscheint mir arg dünn. Mit Wächerin fällt mir auch prompt ein schlechtbezahlter Frauenberuf mit ~in ein. Souffleuse und Dompteuse finde ich noch. Die Ausbreitung der Bedeutung erscheint mir auch recht konstruiert. Ich höre bei Friseuse keine sexuelle Konnotation, erst recht nicht bei Souffleuse oder Dompteuse.

Comment: "Friseur/-euse ergäbe Friseureuse" - aber wohl nur, wenn man es absichtlich falsch verstehen will. Sobald man mehr als ein reines Substantiv nennen muss, wird man nicht umhinkommen, mehrere Wörter/Wortbestandteile aufzulisten, die sich z.T. gegenseitig ausschließen und nicht einfach hintereinander gelesen werden können. "und Friseu(r/se) ist schlicht Unfug." - wieso? Nur, weil es auf Minimierung der Länge statt auf Beibehaltung von Wortstamm und -endung optimiert ist?

Answer (score 7):

From the [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fris%C3%B6r):

> Das Wort leitet sich aus dem Französischen ab, wo das Verb friser soviel wie „kräusen“ bedeutet. Der Begriff Friseur war im Französischen nie sehr gebräuchlich und ist mittlerweile völlig ausgestorben.
>
> Ursprünglich lautete die „offizielle“ weibliche Form der Berufsbezeichnung lange Zeit Friseuse nach der französischen Scheinherkunft. Da diese Bezeichnung jedoch vielfach als abwertend empfunden wurde, setzte sich die Bezeichnung Friseurin durch.

Comment: I saw that too but this merely describes the fact, not *why* it is considered rude. This really would be interesting to know.

Comment: ineresting and a little bit funny german [article](http://www.fembio.org/biographie.php/frau/comments/friseuse-oder-friseurin/)

Comment: I heard it was not at all meant derogative. With the spelling reform in Germany a lot of foreign words were changed into something more fitting to the predominant logic. "Friseuse" was one of these words but some people simply didn't know the reason and the whole "discriminating term" up.

Comment: @con-f-use: I doubt it's connected to the spelling reform - after all, _Friseurin_ is a different word with a different pronunciation!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this is related to *Masseuse* meaning something quite different than *Masseurin* nowadays: The latter is a female *Masseur*, whereas from a *Masseuse* one will probably expect some sexual pleasure. For this reason, a *Masseurin* will be legitimately offended if you call her *Masseuse*. My guess is that this is how *Friseuse* got a negative connotation.

Comment: I don't think so. If you look in Google Ngrams then the change from *Masseuse* to *Masseurin* comes later than the change from *Friseuse* to *Friseurin*.

Comment: @starblue: To me it looks as if the changes happened at about the [same](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Friseuse,Friseurin&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) [time](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Masseuse%2CMasseurin&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3).

Comment: Masseusen, die nicht nur den Rücken massieren bieten aber auch eine Massagetätigkeit an, daher ist es gar nicht möglich hier begrifflich zu differenzieren. Eine Person die im Massagesalon arbeitet kann ebenso, wenn sie sich Masseur/Masseurin nennt erhobene Augenlider erleben.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the only (or at least predominant) reason *Friseuse* was considered inappropriate was that some people used it in a derogatory manner, which was however not due to the word itself but due to the social context and other phenomena (like the Manta jokes). The whole process would have been the same, if another word instead of *Friseuse* had been in use during a certain period of time, e.g., *Friseuse* with a French pronunciation or *Coiffeuse.*

This can be compared to the fact that no matter what word you use for an immigrant, a disabled person or a coloured person, this word will be used derogatorily by a certain kind of people, as long as these people exist. This will make another kind of people consider the word inappropriate and propagate a new word. If the new word is established and the old one is considered inappropriate by a majority, the whole process starts all over again: the [political-correctness treadmill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism_treadmill#Euphemism_treadmill). The only difference with *Friseuse* is that the social context which powered the treadmill ceased to exist.

I am aware, that this hypothesis is very difficult to proof and that other factors might have played into this, e.g., the fact that *Friseuse* is better suited for a derogatory pronunciaton than its alternatives.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117694/discussion-on-answer-by-wrzlprmft-why-is-the-title-friseuse-considered-as-inap).

Answer (score 3):

According to a [job website for hairdressers](https://www.friseur-job.de/friseuse-oder-friseurin/), there's still a discussion within the industry: Some are okay with being called a "Friseuse", especially older hairdressers who earned that title in their professional training. Others consider it rude and offensive.

Part of the reason is, that the "Friseuse" had gotten a less than flattering image. As the aforementioned website puts it

> Viele stört das schlechte Bild, das mit der „Friseuse” verbunden ist. Die Friseurinnen finden, dass die Friseuse eine eher comic-haftes Bild herraufbeschwört: Minirock, pinke Nägel, toupierte Tolle und ein Modegeschmack, der in den 90ern hängen geblieben ist.

which could be translated as

> Many *[who call themselves "Friseurin"]* are bothered with the negative image that is connotated with the "Friseuse". The "Friseurinnen" think that the "Friseuse" conjures up a rather comic-like stereotype: Miniskirt, pink fingernails, big hair and a fashion sense stuck back in the Nineties.

When I was a child some decades ago, the distinction was something like this: A "Friseuse" could be trusted with simple, standard jobs, from sweeping together the cut hair to maybe some routine haircuts. But you'd still keep an eye on her when she wielded sharp objects like scissors. On the other hand, a "Friseurin" was a professional, with professional training and experience, who knew what she was doing, even in more complicated cases. A "Friseurin" could be the owner of the shop, a "Friseuse"... probably not.

Comment: Das ist aber, wie auch bei der Masseuse, eine illusorische Denkweise. Dass die  Masseurin mit Sexdienstleistungen verbunden wird liegt ja daran, dass solche als Massage getarnt werden, nicht am Begriff. Zur Tarnung wird in Zukunft daher häufiger Masseurin verwendet, dann kann man das nächste Wort bekämpfen, und Friseusenwitze wird man zu Friseurinnenwitzen machen und steht da auch wieder, wo man vorher war.

Comment: @userunknown Man könnte jetzt eine Diskussion darüber führen, was ein "Begriff" eigentlich ist und was ein Begriff verursachen kann und was nicht. Am Ende des Tages ist sowohl "Friseuse" als auch "Friseurin" als auch, zum Beispiel, "Apfelkompott" eine Lautfolge (bzw. eine schriftliche Repräsentation davon), die in sich keine Bedeutung hat. Erst die Konvention unter den Verwendern legt fest, was diese Lautfolgen repräsentieren. Und wenn es unter den Verwendern üblich geworden ist, unter "Friseuse" das beschriebene Stereotyp zu verstehen, dann _bedeutet_ der Begriff "Friseuse" genau das.

Comment: Ja, und wenn 3 Idioten beschließen, dass für sie ab sofort "Apfelkompott" "Heil Hitler" bedeuten soll, um gleich in die Vollen zu gehen, kann ich weiter die Eiche spielen, die das nicht juckt, auch wenn es  30% werden.

Comment: @userunknown "3 Idioten" sind nicht "die Verwender", auch nicht "30%". Aber wenn die weit überwiegende Zahl der Sprechenden den Begriff mit einer bestimmten, ggf. gegenüber vorherigen Zeiten veränderten, Bedeutung verwendet, wird es irgendwann albern, die Eiche zu spielen. Über den Einzelfall kann man immer streiten (und auch darüber, wie sinnvoll es ist, sich über den jeweiligen Einfall zu streiten). Aber ein junges Mädchen als "Dirne" anzusprechen, weil "diorna" im Althochdeutschen mal diese Bedeutung hatte, könnte Ärger geben ;)

Comment: @userunknown Mich erinnert diese Haltung an den [Chronozentrismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronozentrismus): "Die Zeit, in der ich zufällig lebe, ist die beste, wenn nicht sowieso die einzig relevante. Und die Version der Sprache, die Version eines Begriffs, die ich ursprünglich gelernt habe, ist die einzig richtige, egal was davor war oder was danach kommt."

Comment: "Spannenlanger Hansel, nudeldicke Dirn', gehn wir in den Garten, pflücken wir die Birn' ...".  Bedenklich ist es, wenn die intellektuelle Elite ihre Sprache an den dümmstmöglichen Ignoranten ausrichtet. Und dumm ist es zu glauben, man dränge die Prostittution dadurch zurück, dass man Wörter tabuisiert. Merkwürdigerweise findet man ja nur Belege dafür, dass manche glauben, Friseuse könne abwertend verstanden werden, aber niemanden, der behauptet, dass es das Wort ist. Dabei ist es der Tonfall, begleitende Gesten etc. die mit "Friseurin" den gleichen Effekt haben, und mit Bundeskanzlerin auch.

Comment: @userunknown Ich finde es bedenklich, wenn man sich selbst zur "intellektuellen Elite" erklärt, und die Mehrheit (den gesamten Rest?) der Sprachgemeinschaft zu den "dümmstmöglichen Ignoranten". Die Bedeutung eines Begriffs wird vom Konsens der Sprachgemeinschaft festgelegt. Wenn eine neue Variante die Sprachgemeinschaft in der Mehrheit überzeugt, wird diese Mehrheit diese Variante verwenden, und die Variante wird sich durchsetzen. Wenn eine neue Variante die Sprachgemeinschaft nicht überzeugt, wird sie wieder verschwinden. Von daher _kann_ ein Wort "es" grundsätzlich nicht sein.

Comment: @userunknown Aber wir kommen gerade ziemlich vom Thema ab. Ich bin daher dafür, diese Diskussion zu beenden.

Answer (score -1):

*Die Antwort auf deine Frage:*

**Friseurin** ist die korrekte Berufsbezeichnung. Dass Berufstätige mit der korrekten Berufsbezeichnung bezeichnet werden wollen, bedarf keiner weiteren Begründung.

Vor einigen Jahren wurde ein Mechatroniker sehr unwirsch, als ich ihn einen "Automechaniker" nannte. Hier ist kaum eine Abwertung zu finden, dennoch wurde die veraltete Bezeichnung als vage Beleidigung empfunden.

*Kritik an deiner Recherche:*

Googles Ngramme reflektieren einzig die Verwendung in der Schriftsprache. Bücher werden aber nur von einem kleinen Teil der Bevölkerung veröffentlicht, die sich zudem deutlich in ihrem Sprachstil von der Durchschnittsbevölkerung abheben. Ein Publizist schreibt in der Regel nicht so, wie ein Bäcker redet. Ob die Verteilung in der gesprochenen Sprache ähnlich ist und ob dort eine ähnliche Veränderung stattgefunden hat und zu welcher Zeit, lässt sich an Googles Ngrammen nicht ablesen.

Unklar ist mir im Moment, ob es einen Zusammenhang mit der Rechtschreibreform geben könnte: Der Trend bei "Friseuse" kehrt sich gerade um, als die neue Rechtschreibung in Kraft tritt. Wurden zu dieser Zeit andere Schreibungen empfohlen oder in Schreibsoftware implementiert? So erscheinen gerade 1993, exakt auf dem Höhepunkt der Friseusen-Kurve, neue Word-Versionen.

Hier wäre eine gründlichere Recherche in die möglicherweise veränderten Entstehungsbedingungen der ausgewerteten Texte notwendig.

Comment: Das [Ngram für Frisöse/Frisörin](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Fris%C3%B6rin%2C+Fris%C3%B6se&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=) zeigt einen ähnlichen Trend und zeigt, wie auch für Friseuse/Friseurin dass die heutige Berufsbezeichnung erst seit den 80er Jahren signifikant vorkommt.

Comment: Interessant. Als ich vorher deinem Link gefolgt bin und dort verschiedene Varianten eingegeben habe, bekam ich häufig die Meldung "Ngrams not found". So finde ich z.B. auch jetzt keine für "Frisörinnen". Hab jedenfall meinen Beitrag entsprechend geändert.

Comment: Doch, genau das, eine Begründung bei mehreren, alternativen Berufsbezeichnungen ist hier gesucht. Das kann nicht einfach per Order di Mufti zum Tabu erklärt werden. Wenn sich ein Hausmeister heute zum Facilitymanager aufblasen will, dann soll er das versuchen - ich muss das nicht mitmachen. Wie heißt eigentlich ein Lokführer offiziell? Ein Soldat? Ein Polizist? Als Laie weiß man es oft gar nicht.

Comment: Ein kurzer Blick in die [Liste der Ausbildungsberufe](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Ausbildungsberufen) liefert ein Haufen offizieller Bezeichnungen, die einem sicher nur auf dem Papier begegnen.