# "zum Zahnarzt" or "zur Zahnärztin" for female dentist?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, gender

> I'm going to see the dentist today.

If the dentist is female, should I say

> (a) Ich gehe heute zur Zahnärztin.

or

> (b) Ich gehe heute zum Zahnarzt.

I think (a) should be the correct version, but I'm not sure whether it's idiomatic. (Perhaps "zum Zahnarzt" is a fixed phrase.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is the gender important for your statement?
In this case: probably no. So use the "neutral" form which is almost always the male form.

If you want to express that you are going to that *type* of person (or shop...) who will finally fix that rotten tooth / cut your hair  / bake & sell bread...    you go

> "zum Zahnarzt" / "zum Friseur" / "zum Bäcker"...

Once you are *not* making a general statement but are talking about the *individual*, the gender should be correct.:

> Ich gehe zu der Zahnärzt**in** in der Goethestraße -> female
>   Meine Friseurin(*) hat ... -> female

There are some exceptions to the "neutral" = "male" rule: "Katze", "Hebamme" (perhaps s.o. else can come up with more examples?) use the female for general / "neutral" statements.

---

(*) Don't use "Friseuse" please!

Comment: This may lead to a conversation like this: A: "Ich geh' heute zum Zahnarzt (male form)." - B: "Zur Kontrolle?" - A: "Nein, sie (female) zieht mir heute einen Zahn."

Comment: Krankenschwester ... männliche Pfleger nennen sich auch manchmal so. Ansonsten gibt's bei Tieren noch so einige Beispiele

Comment: @Emanuel Eine "Krankenschwester" hat mir mal unwirsch entgegengehalten, dass sie keine Nonne sei. Korrekt heißt es "Gesundheits- und Krankenpfleger".

Comment: Oh ja, der Unterschied zwischen formaler und umgangssprachlicher Berufsbezeichnung...

Comment: Es gibt keinen Grund von Friseuse generell abzuraten.

Comment: @userunknown So gerne ich dir zustimmen würde hat mich eine *Friseurin* eines besseren belehrt: Der Begriff *Friseuse* wird, aus mir nicht ganz klaren Gründen, als erniedrigend empfunden =(

Comment: @Jan : Da verweise ich auf die Manta-Filme und -[witze](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantawitz) der späten 80er und frühen 90er. Die *Friseuse* ist die dümmlich-blonde Begleitung des prolligen Mantafahrers und die Personifizierung von "dumm f* gut". Spätestens seit dieser Zeit ist Friseuse ein Begriff mit "Assoziationen".

Comment: @Jan: Anekdotische Evidenz. Ich kenne dagegen 2 Friseusen, die den Begriff nicht abwertend empfinden.

Comment: @Stephie: Und wieso heftet sich die Assoziation an den Begriff und nicht an den Beruf? Das ist keine Erklärung. Eher wäre es eine Erklärung, dass in einem solchen Film behauptet wird, der Begriff sei herabsetzend und dass ein Großteil den Witz nicht geschnallt hat, und jetzt als Weisheit in die Welt hinausträgt.

Comment: @userunknown : Mal andersrum gefragt - wenn es Friseurinnen gibt, die sich nicht als "Friseuse" bezeichnen lassen wollen (und übrigens auch Masseurinnen, die keinesfalls "Masseusen" sind) eben *weil* manchmal die negative Assoziation da ist, sollte man dann im Kontext dieser Frage nicht auf ein potentielles Fettnäpfchen hinweisen, das man durch den - übrigens [korrekten](http://www.friseurhandwerk.de/daten-fakten_beschaeftigte,20_23.html) - Begriff   "Friseurin" ganz leicht umgehen kann? Zumindest bis sich die Assoziation vielleicht wie bei Jan zu sehen durch Generationenwechsel auflöst.

Comment: Wenn mir niemand einen vernünftigen Grund nennen kann, wieso "Friseuse" herabsetzend sein soll, nein. Man sieht einer Friseuse ja nicht an, ob sie Friseuse, Friseurin, Meisterin des Friseurhandwerks oder was immer als herabsetzend betrachtet. Man müsste sonst vollständig verstummen. Wenn mir eine Friseuse persönlich erklärt, dass sie das nicht will nehme ich aber vielleicht auch Rücksicht ohne es zu verstehen. Was man nur versteht, wenn man einen Film gesehen hat, der 500.000 Zuschauer hatte, kann nicht normativ sein.

Comment: @userunknown, willst Du wirklich das [alte Thema](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/why-is-the-title-friseuse-considered-as-inappropriate) aufwärmen? Das hatten wir hier schon 2011. Und der Film sprang lediglich auf die Welle der Mantawitze auf (von denen es noch immer ganze Seiten im WWW gibt), nur als Nebenbemerkung, damit Du das Pferd nicht argumentativ von hinten aufzäumst. Da die Mantawitzwelle vor der Wende war, kann ein Ost-West-Unterschied im Sprachgebrauch zusätzlich eine Rolle spielen. Weitere Diskussionen sollten wir, wenn überhaupt, im Chat führen.

Answer (score 5):

I would stick with the generic masculine version unless the dentists gender matters for some reason. A possibility where (a) might be used is when there are two dentists, one male, one female, and stating gender might clarify which one you are going to see.

Another widely used option would be

> Ich habe heute einen Zahnarzttermin.

which makes clear that this is a fixed appointment that can not be easily shifted to some other time.

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer will depend on your opinions on [gender neutral language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_language).

In certain Bundesländer in Germany, the law proscribes the use of "gender fair" language in official texts such as job ads for teachers. This does not mean that every person has to say "Zahnärztin", but it shows how much awareness for this subject has come. There are women who are offended, some extremely so, by having the male version of their job name applied to them, while others even prefer the male version, which they consider neutral. In the end what you say will depend on how you feel about this topic, or if you want to act politically correct despite other views.

My son, who is seven, says "Zahnärztin", because obviously she is a woman. He corrects me, when I say "Zahnarzt".

Comment: Es gibt keine übergreifend, politisch korrekte Form sondern nur verschiedene politische Anschauungen, bzw. die sprachwissenschaftlichen Evidenzen werden entweder einer politischen Ansicht zu Liebe geopfert, was selbst wieder ein politisches Statement ist, oder man hält an dem, was man für sprachlich richtig erkannt hat fest, auch wenn es politischen Einflußgruppen missfällt, die es partout anders deuten wollen. Sprachwissenschaftlich richtig wird es dadurch aber nicht.

Comment: Da bin ich anderer Meinung, und zwar in Hinsicht auf mehrere Aspekte deines Kommentars, aber das wäre off topic.