# Gender-neutral singular third-person pronoun

Tags: gender, pronoun

I’m writing a German locale for a project/game I’m developing, and some messages require a gender-neutral pronoun to refer to a person. For example, one of the messages is:

> They were a detective.

Does German have a pronoun that fits these needs, or is it better to somehow avoid this requirement and phrase it differently? I did a bit of research, and found nothing even close to a definitive answer.

**Edit:** To provide more context to the example message, this particular one is displayed <s>in a game on the ID tag of a corpse</s> upon a player identifying a body, immediately after the announcement that they have discovered it (“X has found the body of Y’). So, it’s referring to the player to whom the body belonged, whose sex is unknown.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18744/zum-zahnarzt-or-zur-zahn%C3%A4rztin-for-female-dentist

Comment: In what context exactly. I'm asking because you could well say "der jemand" or "die Person", but only if the entity has been established before.

Comment: @Emanuel Apologies, the context I provided was incorrect. I've edited the OP accordingly. In English, the full message would look something like "X has discovered the body of Y. They were a detective."

Comment: "They were detectives" or "He was a detective" or what do you mean?

Comment: "Das war ein Ermittler" would in my old-fashioned mind pretty much fit to both female and male detectives.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/76003/what-should-be-included-in-a-disclaimer-about-the-omission-of-gender-neutral-lan/76009

Answer (score 6):

Gender-neutral, yes (the *es*). Gender-neutral in the sense of either female or male, no (unfortunately).

And even if there was one, the problem would survive in the nature of German nouns: In English, "detective" can be used for both genders, while in the German singular one must choose between *Detektiv* and *Detektivin* (inferring gender).

However, some still consider/perceive the male form as generic, allowing

> Das war ein Detektiv.

to be used in the way you need.

This has become quite disputed, though, and the disputes ultimately lead to "Gendering" in the German language. That means modifying nouns in a way such that they cover both genders (but only if the nouns refer to a mixed group or an unknown individual). Some examples:

> Das war ein/e DetektivIn. *(the big I is called Binnen-I)*
>   Er/sie war ein(e) Detektiv(in).
>   Liebe Detektivinnen und Detektive! *(so even the plural infers gender)*

Optically, this does not look very pretty, yet most public text sources have adopted (some form of) this style. So if the first example doesn't look all too horrid to you, then that's lucky, because I really can't think of some worthy periphrasis (it's difficult without "detective").

<sup>Of course it depends on your audience (and eventually on your superiors) whether you can use the generic masculine or not.

For a game, I believe that a colloquial "Er oder sie war ein Detektiv" would be OK, too, but as said, this is subject to change.</sup>

Lastly, a natural solution would be to let the speaker assume a gender, which is then confirmed or refuted later on. This is often done in movies.

Comment: I have heard the title (not the job) "detective" left untranslated in German versions of US crime shows. Maybe in this specific context here one could leave "detective" in  "Es ist/Das war ein Detective."

Comment: Es ist schlicht falsch, daß man Berufbezeichnungen wie Detektiv im Deutschen immer gendern muß.

Comment: @Ingo [Nicht immer.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allgemeines_Gleichbehandlungsgesetz#Unerlaubte_Diskriminierung_im_Arbeitsrecht)

Comment: @Ingo Es handelt sich um die deutsche Gesetzgebung. Zur Illustration: Gesetz -> Arbeitsrecht -> Personaleinstellung -> Stellenanzeigen/Zeitungsinserate -> Berufsbezeichnungen -> Gleichbehandlung -> Gendern.

Comment: @ Chris — "Das war ein Detective" ändert relativ wenig an der individuellen Geschlechterwahrnehmung, eher an der Deutlichkeit, was die Herkunft und Funktion betrifft: im Deutschen ist ein Detektiv nämlich primär ein Privatdetektiv, nicht ein polizeilicher Ermittler.

Comment: @user6191: Jeder Deutschsprecher weiß, dass ›Detektiv‹ geschlechtsneutral entweder für einen männlichen oder einen weiblichen Detektiv steht. Das Maskulinum ist im Deutschen Standardgenus, dazu bräuchte es eigentlich keine wissenschaftliche Untersuchung. Die gibt es aber auch, womit wir auf einer Seite Sprachgebrauch und Wissenschaft, auf der anderen Seite Ideologie haben. Das Gesetz schreibt Gendern natürlich nicht vor. Es ist ja bereits jeder gleichbehandelt.

Answer (score 3):

> X has found the body of Y.
>   They were a detective.

In this particular case there may be an elegant gender-neutral translation, by not using a pronoun:

> *X hat die Leiche von Y gefunden.*
>   ***Das Opfer** war Detektiv.*

*Leiche* (f.) ‘dead body’ and *Opfer* (n.) ‘victim’ don’t imply a certain sex. 
Alternatively, it also works with using the name of course.

> ***Y** war Detektiv.*

Using *Detektiv* as a predicative without indefinite article *ein* may still be considered sexist by some feminists, but I’ve yet to see a psycholinguistic study to prove there’s a (male) bias in this particular construct. 
Evidence that there’s a bias in some constructs has frequently been (ab)used to justify critique of other constructs.

Neuter nouns like *Opfer, Tier, Kind* or *Mädchen* may always be referred to by masculine base forms of actor nouns (e.g. *Detektiv*), which they share most inflections with (“grammatical agreement”), but the derived feminine form (*Detektivin*) *can* also be used if the sex is known to be female (“natural agreement”) – the tendency to do so is growing.

Although *Leiche* is feminine, it would be (semantically) odd to refer to it with *sie*, because not the body but the person was a detective. Also, *sie* may be thought to refer to the name thereby determining the sex of *Y*.

> *X hat **die Leiche** von Y gefunden.*
>   ***?Sie** war Detektiv.*

It would be less odd with *Opfer*.

> *X hat **das Opfer** gefunden.*
>   ***Es** war Detektiv.*

Alas, a sentence starting with *es war* may easily be misunderstood to be using a filler *es* as in *es war Sommer*. The neuter relative pronoun may be better.

> ***Dieses** war Detektiv.*

That’s still sounding unidiomatic, though, but with an adverbial or a full verb it becomes okayish.

> *Dieses war **zu Lebzeiten** Detektiv.*
>   *Dieses **arbeitete als** Detektiv.*

An apposition could also be used instead. It may be introduced by a colon, en-dash or comma and it’s also possible to surround it by parentheses.

> *X hat die Leiche von Y gefunden **– ein Detektiv**.*
>   *X hat die Leiche von Y **(Detektiv)** gefunden.*

### Singular *they*

There is no direct equivalent to English singular *they* in German. 
Since *sie* is already used for both, (feminine) ‘she’ and (plural) ‘they’, there can’t be.

On the other hand, German *es* (or other neuter pronouns) can be used a bit more freely to refer to human beings than English *it*.

> It’s a detective.
>   *Es ist ein Detektiv.*

PS: I’ve used *Detektiv* as a translation of ‘detective’, but that’s a false friend if the rank or role within the police force was meant.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a game like Mafia or Werewolf where players eliminate each other?

In that case I'd go with "Er oder sie war Detektiv", or you could use tha player's name if you have that: "{Name} war Detektiv."

If gender is not important, you could avoid the problem by writing "Hier liegt ein Detektiv (oder eine Detektivin)".

You could also write "Das war ein Detektiv." but that could be misleading as it could be understood as "a detective killed that person". May depend on the context.

Comment: The gender is more referring the the actual human controlling the character that died, whose gender can't be known. Anyhow, "Das war ein Detektiv" would translate to something like "This (the corpse) was a detective", correct?

Comment: @mproncace Yes. I've updated my answer based on what you said about the game.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not in any way a German speaker. I’ve only just started taking German classes, and it’s the second week of school.

In my most recent class, we started talking about pronouns and how every noun in the German language is gendered. As a Gender Studies major, I got very curious about gender-neutral pronouns that weren’t es, because it’s the equivalent of *it* in English, and as far as I know, nobody particularly liked being called *it*. I did some research and found the blogs of some genderqueer people who live in Germany. Many of them use the pronouns *xier* or *sien* instead of *er/sie.* Others use the plural *Sie.* For nouns, I found that there is one professor in Berlin who prefers to be referred to as *Professx* instead of *Professor/Professorin.* So you could use *Detektix,* or a variation of that.

Comment: Welcome to the German Language SE and thank you for your contribution. As a native speaker, I'd just like to calibrate this answer by saying: These variants do not play any kind of role in standard or every-day german, but are specific to a certain subculture. I.e., the average german speaker will not understand _xier_, _sien_ or _Professx_.

Comment: Your really shouldn't use any of these unless know you exactly what you're doing, and certainly not as a learner of German. Acceptance is not exactly quit there yet, to put it mildly.

Comment: I agree with @hiergiltdiestfu and Ingmar. I'm a German native speaker, and have never heard xier, sien or any of the above, and I wouldn't understand them. So be very careful when using them.

Comment: Good research, but terrible advice. Welcome!

Comment: There's an analog to this in English, something along the lines of "xer" (obviously conjugation is not an issue). However, it is extremely non-standard and generally only used in a specific context (relating to genderqueer-ness), and thus not particularly appropriate in this case. The difference is that the gender is simply unknown as opposed to undefined.

Answer (score -2):

What you are referring to is *third* person, not first person. The first person is 'I' or 'we' (German *ich* or *wir*). Also, what do you mean by 'requirement'?

[Ahem](http://www.condenaststore.com/-sp/Have-you-considered-writing-this-story-in-the-third-monkey-rather-than-th-New-Yorker-Cartoon-Prints_i9114682_.htm)

There is no such thing in German (if you are talking about persons), and not really in English. You would use *er*, just the same as English uses 'he'. *Er* in German encompasses persons of indeterminate sex just as 'he' does in English.

The 'gender-neutral' third person pronoun in English is 'it', which is used of inanimate objects, animals, and occasionally infants whose sex is not easily identifiable. German has *es* as a neuter third-person pronoun, but it is used to refer to grammatically neuter *nouns*, not 'inanimate things'. Since the gender of many German compound nouns is determined by the last component, you have the situation where *Mädchen*, which means 'girl', is not a feminine noun, but a neuter one because the suffix *chen* makes all nouns to which it is attached *neuter*. *Das Mädchen, welches mich liebt, ist sehr schön.* 'The girl who (or 'that') loves me is very beautiful'.

The German pronoun *man*, (not to be confused with *der Mann*, which means 'the man') which means 'one', is masculine (that means that masculine pronouns, such as *sein*, are used with it).

[German declensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension)

It is used in situations where one would use a passive construction in English. *Man glaubt* = 'it is believed', *man arbeitet* = 'one works' etc. 'They were a detective' is improper in English anyway.

When the *sex* of an individual is indeterminate or unspecified, the pronoun 'he' is to be used; 'he' is to be construed as masculine *only* when the antecedent is identified as male; it is indeterminate or neuter if the sex of the antecedent is not specified. It includes males and females. Likewise in German, one uses *er*.

'One takes his place, and he must remain silent'. In German, it would be the same, and the possessive pronoun *sein* would be used. *Man nimmt seinen Platz, und er muss still bleiben.*

One must work hard at his job if he is to succeed.

*Man* takes a *masculine* declension!

Nominative: man

Accusative: einen

Genitive: sein

Dative: einem

Comment: @c.p. ... about "man"... Ornello is right that behaves like it is masculine. "Man kann das Orakel nicht finden. Es findet einen." Neither "eine" nor "eins" would work here. I disagree about "er" though. The only suitable nominative continuation for "man" is... "man". "Er" does strongly imply a subject that is male. The sentence "Man nimmt seinen Platz und er muss still sein" is correct only if "er" is a different entity than "man". The translation would be "One takes his place und he (someone else) must be quiet."

Comment: @Emanuel: "Man geht und nimmt seinen Turnbeutel mit" - "seinen", also sprachlich eine maskuline Fortsetzung. Über die Person und deren Geschlecht sagt das aber nichts aus: "Man kann die Pille oder ein Diaphragma zur Verhütung einsetzen." Ist hier irgendwas männlich? Was? Es ist kein Substantiv welches mit einem Artikel versehen werden kann.

Comment: @userunknown... Dein Beispiel ("seinen") ist ein Beleg dafür, dass "man" nicht weiblich ist. Sonst wäre es ja "ihren Turnbeutel". Mein Beispiel ist 100% eindeutig. Ich ersetze "man" durch ein Indefinitpronomen und die einzige Form, die funktioniert, ist die maskuline. Daher kann man "man" als maskulin kategorisieren. Mit Substantiven hat das nichts zu tun. Hier geht es um Pronomen. In deinem Satz mit der Pille ist "man" maskulin. Wie überall sonst auch.

Comment: **Please avoid overlengthy comment threads. Such discussions should go to [chat]. Once an issue was resolved all comments should be removed. Ideally all valuable comments that don't fit the post they're on should result in an own, additional anwer. Thank you.**