# How do German job ads specify both female and male role types?

Tags: formality, culture

I just saw an job ad on Stack-Overflow in German, and it said

> **Software Entwickler/in**

Is the *Entwickler/in* referring to both genders of developers? And if so, do German job ads typically use this kind of */in* notation to avoid being sexist? Would a woman apply for a job whose ad only specified the male form and vice versa?

Comment: [Related.](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20325/gender-neutral-singular-third-person-pronoun)

Comment: This was enforced by German law ([AGG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/agg/BJNR189710006.html)) in 2006 to ban discrimiation of all kinds. Apart from that the question is not about German language but about German **law**, hence off topic for the site (you may ask however **how** to formulate this in a given context).

Comment: it is about german langauge, it is about gendering of job titles, it is relevant to the law you linked though

Comment: @0xor1 please [edit] your question to focus on the **language** aspect. As it stands now it asks whether we had any regulations for that.

Comment: "do German job ads typically have to use this kind of /in notation to avoid being sexist?" In my experience another common way is to combine the male job title with "(m/w)" which stands for "männlich/weiblich" (male/female), e.g. "Softwareentwickler (m/w)".

Comment: Actually some of the questions are on-topic, but have already been answered, IIRC. Also, I cannot find where the law specifies that using the generic masculine would be discrimination.

Comment: "Softwareentwickler" ist zwar ein Wort mit männlichem Geschlecht, bezeichnet aber Softwareentwickler beiderlei Geschlechts, soweit aus dem Kontext nicht hervorgeht, dass ausschließlich Männer gemeint sind. Insbesondere ist es die neutrale Bezeichnung für Softwareentwickler unbekannten Geschlechts. Interessierte Kreisen versuchen zwar das Gegenteil zu propagieren, liegen aber damit nachweislich falsch.

Comment: @0xor1: a big *political* issue are the misunderstood masculine genera in German. Whoever knows more than one language with different grammatical gender will not be surprised, but politicians don't tend to think out of their boxes. So we disfigure our language in the hope that it will somehow magically solve a social problem. And yes, I am fully with Takkat that this is more of a legal question. But still it's tied to the language, so when it doubt I'd say allow it. It's not like this is one of the most thriving SE sites.

Comment: @0xor1: In English "nurse" used to have a similar connotation, I think. That is: the term used to refer traditionally to female nurses, but was kind of retrofitted to be gender-neutral. This is part of the comedic aspect in "Meet the parents", for example. It's not quite the same as masculine genera, but it's close enough. How ridiculous it is to enforce this, becomes evident quickly. Take *Student* as an example. The politically correct use is *StudentInnen* (so called Binnen-I) or "Student/in" or "Studenten und Studentinnen". But how to form a pc version of "Studentenwohnheim"?

Comment: Why, _StudentInnenwohnheim_ of course, or -- marginally less horrible -- _Wohnheim für Studierende_.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: That is why a general switch to the word "Studierende/r" (whose plural "Studierende" is the same for both genders) can be seen now, so "Studentenwohnheim" becomes "Studierendenwohnheim".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: oh yeah, seen that too. It's just another type of wrongly understood political correctness disfiguring the German language. Often one will hear a justification like "Autoren" just seems to imply an all-male group, so if in the next sentence it would refer to "Frau Meier" as a member of that group or similar it would be odd. However, it would be equally odd if you indicated a group of "Autorinnen" and then mentioned "Herrn Meier" as a member of that group in the next sentence. All attempts of justifications I heard so far had nothing to do with style or linguistic considerations.

Comment: @Takkat: Auf die Schnelle finde ich in dem langen Gesetz nicht den Passus den Du meinen könntest. Kannst Du den Paragraph nennen?

Comment: @userunknown: ist zwar *off topic*, aber es gilt §1 zusammen mit §2.1.1: *Ziel des Gesetzes ist, Benachteiligungen aus Gründen (...) des **Geschlechts** (...) zu verhindern oder zu beseitigen.* und *Benachteiligungen aus einem in § 1 genannten Grund sind nach Maßgabe dieses Gesetzes unzulässig in Bezug auf 1. die Bedingungen, einschließlich **Auswahlkriterien** und **Einstellungsbedingungen**, für den Zugang zu unselbstständiger und selbstständiger Erwerbstätigkeit, unabhängig von Tätigkeitsfeld und beruflicher Position, sowie für den beruflichen Aufstieg (...)*

Comment: Ja, @Takkat, aber "Schreiner" ist eine geschlechtsneutrale Formulierung. Man muss die Sprache absichtlich falsch verstehen um daraus eine Benachteiligung zu konstruieren.

Comment: Hier, bei [belleslettres](http://belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php) wird der ideologische Irrtum mit dem Genus ausführlich erklärt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By law, if you want to employ someone, you can't decide wich gender the person will be. 
That means it is forbidden to send out a job ad only for males or females.

The /in Notation is just short for two words. "Software Entwickler/in" means "Software Entwickler oder Software Entwicklerin". Sometimes its just written with a capital I: "Software EntwicklerIn"

This whole gendering got a little out of hand, and some people speak of the "Genderwahn". (means Gendermadness)

Comment: Das Binnen-I wird in Deutschland kaum noch gebraucht.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ich sehe das immer noch sehr oft. Ich finde dieses Binnen-I persönlich abartig.

Comment: @BarthZalewski die emotionale Reaktion (wobei ich Deine Wortwahl unpassend finde) ist immer eine Frage der eigenen Erfahrung. Das Binnen-I habe ich Ende der Achtziger als taz-Leser positiv mit einer progressiven oder links-alternativen Haltung verbunden. Ich habe es etwas vermisst, als es irgendwann fast ganz aus der taz verschwunden ist. Andererseits konnte ich, als ich im letzten Sommer in einem Café ein Gespräch junger Leute über die Wichtigkeit des [Gender Gap](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_Gap_%28Linguistik%29)s mitgehört habe, das nicht ganz ernst nehmen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: man sieht es schon noch. Aber wichtiger: in einer vollständigen Erklärung sollte es nicht fehlen :)

Comment: Softwareentwickler sollte so oder so kein Deppinnenleerzeichen beinhalten.

Answer (score 13):

Just to add one more thing. You can also satisfy the legal requirement by hiring:

### Softwareentwickler (m/w)

where the *(m/w)* indicates "männlich" (male) and "weiblich" (female) respectively.

You can find that also relatively often these days (but of course *that*, i.e. the perceived frequency, is my subjective view).

Comment: It's pretty common. Especially, as it could be rendered as *Software Developer (m/w)*, where no normal female form exists.

Answer (score 7):

Auf [bellelettres](http://belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php) ist ein Oberlandesgerichtsurteil dokumentiert, welches in einem Fall die Notwendigkeit ausdrücklicher Beidnennung bejaht hat, aber der Autor zeigt, dass dieses Urteil zwar einen Kommentar zum Gesetz zitiert, jedoch einen entscheidenden Teil des Kommentars unterschlagen hat, um daraus eine Begründung zu zimmern.

Fakt ist, dass die Entwicklung der dt. Sprache beweist, dass das generische Maskulinum ein Phänomen der Sprache ist und die männliche Form eines Wortes nichts über das Geschlecht des Bezeichneten verrät.

Fakt ist auch, dass Richter nicht den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch des Deutschen festlegen können. Man muss die Fehlinformation, dass Softwareentwickler nur Männer meint, für evident halten, um daraus eine Ungleichbehandlung abzuleiten. Sprachwissenschaftlich kann das nicht gezeigt werden, sondern das Gegenteil ist wahr.

Laut Gesetz ist keine Doppelnennung nötig, sondern nur ein nichtdiskriminierendes Verhalten. Bei korrekter Kenntnis der deutschen Sprache sollte also keine Doppelnennung nötig sein, bei Kenntnis deutscher Gerichte kann man dazu aber nicht uneingeschränkt raten.

Anders verhält es sich bei der ausschließlichen Verwendung der weiblichen Form. Softwareentwicklerin ist nicht generisch und bezeichnet ausschließlich Frauen.

Comment: Keine Antwort auf die Frage.

Comment: Die Gerichte sind in ihrer Beweiswürdigung frei. Wenn bspw. eine Firma bisher ausschließlich männliche Softwareentwickler hat und eine qualifizierte Bewerberin abgelehnt wird, liegt der Verdacht auf Diskriminierung nahe. ("Passt nicht ins Team.") Wenn dann noch die Stellenanzeige der Firma zu den wenigen gehört, die nicht auch die weibliche Form extra aufführen, wird aus dem Verdacht zu Recht schnell die Überzeugung des Richters. (Oder der Richterin, da wir gerade beim Thema sind...)

Comment: @Hans: Softwareentwickler und Richter hast du intuitiv als Neutrum verwendet!

Comment: @HansAdler: <b>Wenn</b>. Und wenn nicht, dann nicht. Deine Spekulationen sind ja durch keine Belege gestützt und daher wertlos. Die Frage ist ja, ob juristisch die sprachliche Form vorgegeben ist. Im allgmeinen wissen Bewerber nicht, ob nur Männer im Betrieb arbeiten, und sellbst wenn kann es sein, dass sich noch keine Frau beworben hat, oder keine hinreichend qualifizierte Frau usw.

Comment: @falkb: Neutrum ist etwas anderes. Dass man manchmal zur Klarstellung "männliche Softwareentwickler" oder "weibliche Krankenschwestern" schreiben muss, heißt noch lange nicht, dass es in jedem Kontext in Ordnung ist, die umgekehrte Präzisierung zu unterlassen, wenn man das jeweils ungewöhnliche Geschlecht (wirklich oder angeblich) mitmeint. Der Sexismus der Grammatik spiegelt den Sexismus in unseren Köpfen wieder und verstärkt ihn. Er ist wegen der schnellen Reaktionen der Sprache kein sinnvoller Ansatzpunkt für weitreichende Änderungen, ihn abzustreiten ist aber lächerlich.

Comment: @user unknown: Das war in dem zitierten Urteil tatsächlich das Problem, weil das Unternehmen anonym blieb. Die Frau wurde erst gar nicht zum Vorstellungsgespräch eingeladen. Bei Geschäftsführerposten muss man eine Geschlechterdiskriminierung leider als normal ansehen. Eine Ausschreibung, die nicht ansatzweise auf das Problem eingeht, wird daher von einigen potenziellen Bewerberinnen als abschreckend angesehen und verringert so die Anzahl weiblicher Bewerbungen. Wenn ein Unternehmen das in Kauf nimmt, ist es in der Beweislast, dass das nicht beabsichtigt war. Der kam das Unternehmen nicht nach.

Comment: @Hans: Sexismus in der Grammatik zu sehen ist eine paranoide Folge davon sich vom Sexismus in den Köpfen zu distanzieren. Den Gartenzaun grün zu streichen, deutet z.B. noch lange nicht auf die favorisierte Partei hin.

Comment: @falkb..."Der Kanzler" ist ein Mann. Historie und Wissenschaft hin oder her.

Comment: @Emanuel: Art. 62 GG: "Die Bundesregierung besteht aus dem Bundeskanzler und aus den Bundesministern."

Comment: "Der Kanzler" im weiteren Sinne ist ein neutraler Oberbegriff, im engeren Sinne ein Mann. Ruf doch mal bei einer Klempnerfirma an und sag: "Könnten Sie mir bitte einen Handwerker oder Handwerkerin vorbeischicken?". Die werden sich totlachen... Die Katze ist z.B. auch im weiteren Sinne der Oberbegriff für die Art, im engeren Sinne die Frau vom Kater.

Comment: @falb... es geht darum, welche Assoziation im Kopf des Hörers entsteht, und ohne wissenschaftliche Belege zu haben, bin ich mir sicher, dass die Mehrheit an eine männliche Person denkt. Das kann durchaus in 10 Jahren anders sein. In Italienisch ist es ja auch kein Problem. Aber ich denke nicht, dass irgendjemand "Kanzler Merkel" hören oder lesen könnte, ohne irritiert zu sein. Mein Punkt ist nicht, dass man alles immer gendern sollte. Mein Punkt ist, dass im kollektiven Bewusstsein die männliche Form eben eher als Mann verstanden wird und nicht als pures Neutrum so wie in Italienisch.

Comment: @Emanuel: In deinem Bsp. handelt es sich um den Übergang zur Verwendung des Begriffs im engeren Sinne, welcher normal für den Fall ist, dass das Geschlecht bekannt ist. Auf eine allgemeine Anfrage (ganz normal unter Verwendung des neutralen Oberbegriffs) "Wer ist denn hier König in diesem Land?" antwortet man geschlechtsspezifisch "Königin ..." bzw. neutral "Wir haben keinen König".