# Lehrer, Lehrerin, Lehrerinnen; das Suffix der Nomen

Tags: noun, gender

Ich möchte gerne wissen, ob es besonderen Regeln für das Suffix der Pluralform der Nomen gibt. Kurzum werde ich immer verwirrt, wenn ich etwas benennen will.

Zum Beispiel:

1. Forsch**er** - Mann
2. Forscher**in** - Frau
3. Forscherinn**en** - Plural

Aber:

1. Architek**t** - Mann
2. Architekt**in** - Frau
3. Architekt**en** - Plural

Und weiter:

1. Freund - Mann
2. Freund**in** - Frau
3. Freund**e** - Plural
4. Freund**innen** - Viele viele Frauen?

Entschuldigung für meine einfache Frage, aber ich kann nichts im Internet finden.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18744/zum-zahnarzt-or-zur-zahnärztin-for-female-dentist/18746#18746

Comment: "Forscherinnen" ist nicht der Plural von "Forscher".

Answer (score 8):

Es gibt verschiedene mögliche Suffixe für den Plural. Diese Suffixe hängen davon ab, zu welcher [Flexionsklasse](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-N/Texte/Flexionskl.html) ein Wort gehört.

Vereinfacht gesagt: Diese Klassen legen fest, ob ein **n/en**, oder ein **e**, ein **r/er**, oder ein **s** angehängt wird, um den Plural zu bilden.

In den genannten Beispielen ist *zusätzlich* noch von Bedeutung, ob man die männliche oder die weibliche Form verwendet.

Für den Fall von "*Freunde*" war schon alles richtig. In den anderen Fällen müßte man genauer unterscheiden:

- Forscher - Mann
- **Forscher - Plural (nur Männer oder Männer und Frauen)**
- Forscherin - Frau
- Forscherinnen - Plural **(Nur Frauen)**

und

- Architekt - Mann
- Architekten - Plural **(nur Männer oder Männer und Frauen)**
- Architektin - Frau
- **Architektinnen - Plural (Nur Frauen)**

Die Deutsche Sprache bevorzugt in vielen Fällen den Gebrauch der männlichen Form, bzw. der Form, bei der Männer oder Frauen gemeint sind. Allerdings ist das in den letzten Jahren heftig diskutiert worden, und immer häufiger wird versucht, eine "neutrale" Formulierung zu finden. Welche Auswirkungen das hat, kann man an anderer Stelle nachlesen. Auf die Beispiele bezogen würde man dann umständlich von

- Architekten und Architektinnen
- ArchitektInnen (mit großem "I")
- Architekten (m/w)

reden.

Comment: Hallo und willkommen! Ein Verbesserungsvorschlag zur sehr umfassenden Antwort: Statt "Männer oder Frauen" könntest du vielleicht "nur Männer oder Männer und Frauen" schreiben, dann sind in der Logik der Formulierung wirklich alle Kombinationen abgedeckt...

Comment: @Stephie Der Plural "Forscher" kann sich sowohl auf 2 Männer, als auch auf 2 Frauen, als auch auf 1 Mann und 1 Frau beziehen. Aber um nicht auf Erklärungen wie die, dass es sich bei dem "oder" um eine nicht-ausschließende Disjunktion handelte, ausweichen zu müssen, habe ich es mal wie vorgeschlagen abgeändert.

Comment: Deshalb habe ich bei der Frage auf einen anderen Post gelinkt, der genau das ausführlich diskutiert. Kann man aber auch in dieser Antwort ggf. im letzten Absatz ausführlicher beleuchten.

Comment: Ich danke euch, euren Antworten und Kommentare sind wirklich hilfreich!

Comment: Die Antwort lässt leider den gerne übersehene Möglichkeit aus, dass das Geschlecht unbekannt/unbedeutend ist. "Wir brauchen 2 Architekten" sagt eben nicht, dass wenn einer davon eine Frau ist, der zweite ein Mann sein muss. Es ist nicht entweder Männer oder gemischtgeschlechtlich, sondern es ist per se nicht geschlechtsmarkierend. Nur wenn man weiß, dass es ausschließlich Männer sind, bleibt es bei "Architekten", während wenn man weiß, dass es ausschließlich Frauen sind, "Architektinnen" möglich ist. "Architekten" bleibt aber nach wie vor möglich. Analog: "Die Katzen"

Comment: @userunknown Die Antwort wurde geschrieben, bevor das "das dritte Geschlicht" "offiziell" wurde. Zum Glück setzt sich langsam die Erkenntnis durch, das z.B. "Architekt" ein Wort ist, dessen *grammatikalisches* Geschlecht männlich ist, das aber mit dem "biologischen" Geschlecht **nichts** zu tun hat (und wenn die Frage relevant wäre, könnte man von "der männliche Architekt" oder "**der** webiliche Architekt" reden). Demnach steht in Stellenausschreibungen inzwischen "Architekt\*", mit der \*Fußnote: "Das 'biologische' Geschlecht ist egal" (und das wird irgendwann auch wieder wegfallen)

Answer (score 2):

Meiner Meinung nach ist das neumodischer Unfug: "Forscher" ist ein Beruf und keine Person, also "der Beruf" und "der Forscher".
Feministen möchten natürlich eine "Berufin" und "Forscherin" als Beruf haben.
Das diskriminiert (IMHO) deutlich, denn es ist klar, daß dann "Forscherin" was anderes als "Forscher" ist. Bloß gut, daß das neue dritte Geschlecht mit der männlichen Form ("das Beruf", "das Forscher") zusammenfällt.
Ja, mir ist bewußt, daß diese Antwort nur wenigen gefallen wird.

Comment: Inhaltlich stimme ich Dir da sogar weitgehend zu, formell gesehen ist dies aber ein Kommentar und keine Antwort.

Answer (score 1):

Die Plurale sind:

> Die Forscher (Männer)/ Die Forscherinnen (Frauen)
>
> Die Architekten (Männer) / Die Architektinnen (Frauen)
>
> Die Freunde (Männer) / Die Freundinnen (Frauen)

Die maskuline Pluralform wird auch oft verwendet, um sich auf die Kategorie im Allgemeinen zu beziehen.

Comment: “Freundin”: German has no specific word for “girlfriend” which is not the same as “female friend”.